# Controller class returned object not mapping to HTML

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Heres my controller class:

```
    @RequestMapping("/viewemp")  
    public ModelAndView viewemp(ModelAndView model){  
    List<Employee> list=new ArrayList<Employee>();  
    list.add(new 
    Employee("Rahul","abc@gmail.com","9985213655","Hyderabad",new 
    java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
    model.addObject("list",list);
    model.setViewName("viewemp"); 
    return model;

}
```

Below is the viewemp.html

```
   <body>

   <table border="2" width="70%" cellpadding="2">  
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Contact</th><th>City</th> 
   <th>Created_On</th></tr>  

  <c:forEach var="emp" items="${list}">   
 <tr>  
 <td>${emp.Name}</td>  
 <td>${emp.Email}</td>  
 <td>${emp.Contact}</td>  
 <td>${emp.City}</td>
 <td>${emp.date}</td>   
 </tr>  
 </c:forEach>  

 </table>  
 </body>
```

Attached output on UI.

Name    Email   Contact City    Created_On
${emp.Name} ${emp.Email}    ${emp.Contact}  ${emp.City} ${emp.date}

Question: How to show the value on UI?

Comment: Could you please specify, what is the current behaviour? Does your code throw any exception, or does it display blank page?

Comment: which annotation you have top of the controller ?

Comment: There are no exceptions. I can see the output. In the output headers are displayed but the data is coming like: ${emp.Name}  ${emp.Email} ${emp.Contact} ${emp.City} ${emp.date}   ...................... @Controller is the annotation on top of the controller class

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `c` JSTL tag declaration in your view file

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

or your Spring configuration doesn't parse the view file correctly and outs `<c:forEach>` as a HTML tag. Check the page source to confirm.